# Mobile Site Default Page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Ripping my brain out over this one, and it's probably something simple that I'm missing. I have a Wordpress site for a client. Initially, she had setup some page using whatever wysiwyg system IPage uses. The mobile site would default to her old page, while the regular site worked fine. I deleted the index.html for the site she originally created...and you can guess what I've ended up with. 404. Any ideas?

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is except accidentally deleting a file.

Comment: There's not enough info to help. Can you post relevant excerpts from `index.html`, `index.php` and `.htaccess`. Check the guides [ask] and http://sscce.org

Comment: I apologize. 

The problem was when pulling up the mobile site, it would default to her old design that we abandoned, instead of the new wordpress design that I created for her. The old design was created with Weebly and after combing through the .htaccess file, I found some remnants of a rewrite cond.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out. In the .htaccess file, Weebly (which is the drag and drop system she used for the original design) included a snippet of code that redirected mobile users to an index.html. Once I removed that snippet, all was fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference, the snippet of code was some PHP of `header('Location: index.html')` or extra `.htaccess` code?

Comment: It was a rewrite of mobile rules.

Comment: I see, these WYSIWGY sites (e.g. [WIX](http://www.wix.com/)) are a nightmare sometimes for us developers aren't they?! :X glad you were able to sort it out - you can accept your own answer too mind you =)